# Why does Windows client say my Debian Samba share is out of disk space? (when it's not)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, samba

I got a small Debian server with a 2 TB HDD as storage mounted. The Samba server is configured to use this HDD as storage.

If I want to copy some large files from my Windows client to the SMB share Windows shows a warning that I'm out of space on that share.

Output from `df` (`/dev/sdb` is the 2 TB disk):

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0       112745160  8001956   98993036   8% /
udev                10240        0      10240   0% /dev
tmpfs             1616972     9116    1607856   1% /run
tmpfs             4042424        0    4042424   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120        0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             4042424        0    4042424   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2          241965    34184     195289  15% /boot
/dev/sda1          523248      132     523116   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb       1922729864 10960320 1814093816   1% /media/hdd
```

Output from `fdisk -l` (just for the HDD):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 118 GiB, 126701535232 bytes, 247463936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 93CB310F-799C-4FC3-865E-FD1DCE3CAF21
```

My `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
workgroup = smb
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browsable = no
read only = no
create mode = 0750

[public]
path = /media/hdd/storage/
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = smb share
printable = no
guest ok = yes
force user = nobody
force group = nogroup
create mask = 777
directory mask = 777
```

The SMB runs without any permission or user restrictions (small home server and I'm the only user).

Why is Windows telling me that the SMB is running out of space?

Comment: What filesystem are you using for your shared drive, and how large are the individual files?

Comment: ext3 and files up to 10gb. copying single files does work until the said disk space warning.

Comment: I've tried copying the files one by one. This works. It seems that the problem is just when copying all files at once. Is there some kind of 
size limitation copy operations?

Comment: Hmm, there shouldn't be. Perhaps either Samba or Windows gets the free space check wrong. Is it a 32-bit server?

Comment: Nope, x64 cpu and debian.